# objc_msgSend_fpret error

Tags: iphone

I am getting a crash in my application.I have checked for deallocated instances using nszombie.still nothing is displayed .The last two lines executed are

```
#0  0x02cf6a3f in objc_msgSend_fpret

#1  ??
```

what may be the reason for this error.

Comment: When are you getting the crash? Are those the only errors displayed?

Comment: this happens soon after a tableview is displayed..i tried to check which line of code is causing the crash but ...it happens after return cell is called for the last cell and debug cursor goes into assembly code.and no other error is shown in the console

Comment: Can you post the code of this method, then? It could be useful...

Comment: sorry i cant post the code here due to nda with the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some shots in the dark:

- Have you tried to return an empty, default cell to see if the error is the same?
- Are you POSITIVE that you're not returning the wrong pointer? (happens more often that you'd imagine)
- If you're not using ARC, are you positive you're not returning an "released" object (not autorelease, just release).
- Are you returning the same cell reference to more than one row? (I have ran into trouble when I stored one cell and returned it to two different indexPath that were showing at the same time).

Comment: well it turned out to be a variable which was released ,it is strange that nszombie could not find it

Comment: I've ran into that before. In that exact same place (creating cells for a table view). That's why it's one of the "shots".

Answer (score 2):

With XC 4.2 stack traces are not symbolcated correctly. Try adding this to your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);
    ....
}
```

Then this function:

```
void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSArray *stack = [exception callStackReturnAddresses];
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", stack);    
}
```

Doesn't always work, but it may help.

Comment: i added the above code in appdelegate..still it doesnt show anything in the console